# How to change multiple to single in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, dropdown

I have two dropdown menu in my HTML, Am trying to work a way around it that when I select **"Multiple"** in the first dropdown the second dropdown can be multiple="multiple" and when I select **Single** on the first dropdown the second dropdown can be set to single and not multiple and finally when I select **Others** the second dropdown will be single too. Below is my code:

```html
<!------------------------- First Dropdown -------------------------->
<div class="ss-custom-select">
  <select class="full-width" id="blocation" name="blocation">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the number of physical location</option>

    <option value="One">Single</option>
    <option value="Multiple">Multiple</option>
    <option value="Online">Others</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!------------------------- Second Dropdown -------------------------->
<div class="ss-custom-select">
  <select class="full-width" id="subtype" name="subtype[]" multiple="multiple">

    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the subtype of business</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('#blocation').addEventListener('change', e => {
  let multiple = [null, false, true, false][e.target.selectedIndex];
  document.querySelector('#subtype').multiple = multiple;
});
```

```html
    <!------------------------- First Dropdown -------------------------->
    <div class="ss-custom-select">
      <select class="full-width" id="blocation" name="blocation">
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the number of physical location</option>

        <option value="One">Single</option>
        <option value="Multiple">Multiple</option>
        <option value="Online">Others</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!------------------------- Second Dropdown -------------------------->
    <div class="ss-custom-select">
      <select class="full-width" id="subtype" name="subtype[]" multiple="false" >

        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the subtype of business</option>
        <option value="1">abc</option>
        <option value="2">def</option>
        <option value="3">ghi</option>

      </select>
    </div>
```

Is that working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean. Something like this?
At least maybe something to work on

```js
function setSecondDropdown(){
let firstDrop = document.getElementById("blocation");

let text = firstDrop.options[firstDrop.selectedIndex].text;
text = text == "Others" ? "Single" : text;
let secondDrop = document.getElementById("secondDropdown");
document.getElementById("secondDiv").style.display = "block";
secondDrop.options[0].text = text;
 
}
```

```html
<!------------------------- First Dropdown -------------------------->
<div class="ss-custom-select">
  <select class="full-width" id="blocation" name="blocation" onchange="setSecondDropdown()">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the number of physical location</option>

    <option value="One">Single</option>
    <option value="Multiple">Multiple</option>
    <option value="Online">Others</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!------------------------- Second Dropdown -------------------------->
<div id="secondDiv" class="ss-custom-select" style="display: none;">
  <select id="secondDropdown"class="full-width" id="subtype" name="subtype[]" multiple="multiple">

    <option value="">Select the subtype of business</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: how can the multiple changes to single on single select? I mean the <select multiple="multiple" ></select> to <select multiple="false" ></select>